# Move cursor to non-adjacent cell after pasting

Tags: excel, vba

My spreadsheet has several non-adjacent blocks of cells to be filled in: A3:D4, F3:I7, K3:N7, then A9:D10, F9:I13, K9:N13, etc.  I paste data copied from the Internet into each block, one after the other.  Once I paste into one block, I would like the cursor to automatically shift to the start of the next block ready for the next paste, i.e. to F3 when A3:D4 is pasted, to K3 when F3:I7 is pasted, to A9 when K3:N7 is pasted, etc.

I found and tried this macro for practice before trying to adapt it, but could not get it to work because it was not even listed in the Alt-F8 menu. It seems to be close to what I need, in that it appears to be "once A1 has a value, move the cursor to C15; once C15 has a value, go to F9; once F9 has a value, go back to A1".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Select Case Target.Address()
Case "$A$1"
    Range("$C$15").Select
Case "$C$15"
    Range("$F$9").Select
Case "$F$9"
    Range("$A$1").Select
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "brute force" approach might be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:D4")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("F3:I7").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("F3:I7")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("K3:N7").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("K3:N7")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A9:D10").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("A9:D10")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("F9:I13").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("F9:I13")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("K9:N13").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("K9:N13")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("A3:D4").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Assuming you have correctly placed the code in the code-module of the worksheet that you wish the code to apply to, you shouldn't expect the macro to appear when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> as it is marked as being `Private`.  It will, however, operate whenever you change the value of one of the cells in the relevant ranges.

---

As Scott beat me to the answer, I decided to go one better and add a "calculation" based approach so that the areas being selected aren't limited to the six you mention in the question.  The following code will go from `A3:D4` to `F3:I7` to `K3:N7` to `A9:D10` to `F9:I13` to `K9:N13` to `A15:D16` to `F15:I19` ... ad infinitum.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 1, 2, 3, 4
            Select Case Target.Row Mod 6
                Case 3, 4
                    Cells(6 * ((Target.Row - 3) \ 6) + 3, "F").Resize(5, 4).Select
            End Select
        Case 6, 7, 8, 9
            Select Case Target.Row Mod 6
                Case 2
                Case Else
                    Cells(6 * ((Target.Row - 3) \ 6) + 3, "K").Resize(5, 4).Select
            End Select
        Case 11, 12, 13, 14
            Select Case Target.Row Mod 6
                Case 2
                Case Else
                    Cells(6 * ((Target.Row - 3) \ 6) + 9, "A").Resize(2, 4).Select
            End Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the "Brute Force" macro, but after pasting data into A3:D4 the cursor stayed put in A3.  The worksheet, named Odds, is one of eight in a workbook.  I right-clicked on that sheet under Microsoft Excel Objects then Insert > Module opened blank Module 5 and I copied the code into that module.  Is that what/all I am supposed to do to get it to work?  Tried filling A3:D4 manually with Tab and Enter to see if pasting was the problem, but still no go to F3.  Will try the Select Case one once I get to grips with Brute Force.  Thanks so far Scott and YowE3K.

Comment: @MarkY The `Worksheet_Change` code needs to go into the code module for the worksheet itself, so right-click on that sheet under Microsoft Excel Objects **then click on View Code**.  (Or just double-click on the sheet name under Microsoft Excel Objects - that will also open up that sheet's code module.)

Comment: Wow YowE3K!  That did the trick.  "Brute force" works like a charm.  No doubt the Select Case one will, too.  Many thanks.  This was my first foray into vba.  All my previous macros  have been simple recorded ones.  At 72, I'm probably a bit old to start delving into the intricacies of vba code, so having access to people like you is just fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted had the right idea, but used the wrong methods in this case. 
I just tested the below code and it works.

*it was not even listed in the Alt-F8 menu* - It will not show up in the Macro Dialogue Box List as it is a [Worksheet_Change Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel), which is by nature private code and cannot be run stand-alone. It must be placed inside the worksheet object you are acting against.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("C15").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C15")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("F9").Select
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("F9")) Is Nothing Then
        Me.Range("A1").Select
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: LOL - I was just about to hit "Post your answer" and noticed yours appear.  The question had been sitting unanswered for 2 hours, and then we both go to answer within a minute of each other.